# ERROR: query has no destination for result data in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am normalising addresses in my `old_users_data` table to split them into separate `location` and `city` tables. For this, I made a function that loops through old users rows and creates location and city records as required. [Dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c8ef9cc5e85bd957e862d45118c399f7)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func() 
RETURNS BOOL AS

$$
DECLARE
    temprow record;
BEGIN
FOR temprow IN 
    SELECT * FROM old_users_data oud
    LOOP

    with city as (
        insert into city (name)
        select temprow.city
        where not exists(
            select id from city where name = temprow.city
        )
        returning id),

        locations AS (
        INSERT INTO locations
            (address, city)
        select temprow.address, id from city
        RETURNING id
        )
    INSERT INTO users (name, location)
        SELECT temprow.name, id
        FROM locations
        RETURNING id;


        raise notice 'Value: %, %', temprow.id, temprow.city;
END LOOP;
RETURN TRUE;
END;
$$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
SELECT test_func();
```

But I am getting the error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_func() line 9 at SQL statement
```

despite having a return statement.

Here is my data:
**old_users_data** table

```
+----+--------+---------------------------+----------+
| id |  name  |          address          |   city   |
+----+--------+---------------------------+----------+
|  1 | sam    | 228 Park Ave S            | New York |
|  2 | rachel | 8474 Augusta St. Brooklyn | New York |
+----+--------+---------------------------+----------+
```

**users** table

```
+----+--------+-------------+
| id |  name  | location_id |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 | sam    |           1 |
|  2 | rachel |           2 |
+----+--------+-------------+
```

**location** table

```
+----+---------------------------+---------+
| id |          address          | city_id |
+----+---------------------------+---------+
|  1 | 228 Park Ave S            |       1 |
|  2 | 8474 Augusta St. Brooklyn |       1 |
+----+---------------------------+---------+
```

**city** table

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | New York |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: Remove the `RETURNING id;` from the last INSERT in your CTE.

Comment: I already have `return true` at the end. I removed the `RETURNING id;` and the error resolved. However, only one user got inserted, not the other. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=39043055e6223dca397e53ea574914b5

Comment: Only one row for each unique city is getting inserted, in the new users table. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=66ee6e7af04c28118cc4685dd5c7d28f

Comment: You don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for that: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2f27a7890b32b85af07dcccae0c365b4

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is duplicating cities in the city table. I assume this is happening because `where not exists(select * 
                     from city 
                     where city.name = oud.city)` is run only in the beginning, when city table is null. So `New York` is inserted twice.

Comment: Using DISTINCT solves that: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=04be5a291bc3c8ee21e46e97724800d3

Comment: Works! Please put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can advice another approach to solve this problem in 3 query:

1. Generate cities table:

```
insert into city ("name") select distinct city from old_users_data;
```

2. Generate locations table:

```
insert into locations ("address", "city_id")
select distinct address, city.id as city_id 
from old_user_data join city on city.name = old_user_data.city;
```

3. Generate users table:

```
insert into users ("name", "location_id") 
select oud.name, l.id as location_id 
from old_user_data as oud
join city c on oud.city = c.name
join locaton l on l.name = oud.address and l.city_id = c.id;
```